# InfluxDB 2.7 discards the whole batch of metrics in case of a serialization issue in a single metric

Tags: influxdb, logstash-configuration, influxdb-2

Recently we did migration from the InfluxDB 1.8 to the InfluxDB 2.7
and it seems that we discovered a kind of error that we have never seen
in the v.1.8

After some investigation we identified that in case of error in one metric
a whole batch of metrics that should be written at this moment is canselled.
This is usually indicated as a gap in the Grafana chart.

About our environment:
-Kafka topic which contains metrics
-Logstash pipeline that reads them from the topic and writes to the InfluxDB 2.7

Current solution that I found:
Identify the error with incorrect metric (for example attempt to write integer to the field with type ofboolean)

```
[app_influxdb2_metrics] Non recoverable exception while writing to InfluxDB {:exception=>#<InfluxDB::Error: {"code":"invalid","message":"unable to parse 'metrics.counters,container_name=container-with-error-metric,level=metrics.counter,datacenter=test cacheMiss={\"cacheKeyPrefix\"=\u003e\"container-with-error-metric::message-hash::\", \"cacheStore\"=\u003e\"redis\"},timestamp=\"2023-08-13T08:09:06.791Z\" 1691914146791': invalid boolean
```

and drop it on a Logstash pipeline level.

```
if [container_name] == "container-with-error-metric" {
    drop {
    }
}
```

I also found a similar bug related to telegrap agent

```
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/5858
```

I also suppose that the error might be fixed and handled on Logstash part, but I have not investigate this yet.

Is there any adjustment in InfluxDB 2.7 which would allow to ignore or abort a single metric and allow all other metrics that should be written at the same time to be recorded to InfluxDB 2.7 database?

Thanks.

=====

I received the answer from the InfluxDB team.

I wouild like to add it here and hope that it will save
someone's time in case if they get a similar question:

I don’t believe that there is that type of solution in 2.x.

I would actually wait on migrating to 2.x.

OSS 3.x is coming out later this year and supports influxQL and many features in 2.x aren’t on the roadmap for 3.x currently. 3.x also has significant performance enhancements.